# how to retrive payload data of restful web service in java using jersey and json

Tags: java, mysql, json, jersey, payload

I am doing restful webservice in java using Jersey,Json and mysql .
By using POST method of chrome's advanced rest client i am sending json data through payload.
Now i want to read that json data in my java file how to do this ?

My code :--

```
public ArrayList<FeedObjects> GetStudent(Connection connection) throws Exception
{
    ArrayList<FeedObjects> feedStudent = new ArrayList<FeedObjects>();
    try
    {
        //String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
        //PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT book_id,bookname,price,author FROM book ORDER BY book_id DESC");

        PreparedStatement ps1 = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM student,CollegeMaster where student.c_id=1 AND CollegeMaster.c_id = 1");
        //ps.setString(1,uname);
        //ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
        while(rs1.next())
        {
            FeedObjects feedObject = new FeedObjects();

            feedObject.setS_id(rs1.getString("s_id"));
            feedObject.setS_name(rs1.getString("s_name"));
            feedObject.setS_address(rs1.getString("s_address"));
            feedObject.setS_contact(rs1.getString("s_contact"));
            feedObject.setS_class(rs1.getString("s_class"));
            feedObject.setC_name(rs1.getString("c_name"));
            feedObject.setC_address(rs1.getString("c_address"));
            feedStudent.add(feedObject);
        }
        return feedStudent;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

i have {"c_id":"1"} from advanced rest client's payload (payload of POST method) which is in json.
Now I want to read this c_id from my java program and then,
As from above code .. I want to add that c_id=1 into query written below.
PreparedStatement ps1 = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM student,CollegeMaster where student.c_id=1 AND CollegeMaster.c_id = 1");

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please put some code and explain more what you want. Thank you

Comment: @Amir sir please reply the above question.As I want to read that json requested from client through payload in my web service api POST.

Answer (score 0):

Hello This is My working example for you.

Create first action class like this where you can read your json and perform your logic 
whatever you want.

```
package com.webapp.actions.api.task;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.webapp.models.TaskModel;
import com.webapp.models.UserModel;

@Path("/api/task")
public class TaskAction extends BusinessApiAction {

@POST
@Consumes({ "application/json", "application/xml" })
@Produces({ "application/json", "application/xml" })
public Response insertTask(TaskModel taskModel) throws IOException {


    //you can print values in taskModel (your json)

    // insert u=your logic for work on your json data.  


   }
}
```

Also design model class according to your json 
ex. here

```
package com.webapp.models;
public class TaskModel  


private String taskId;
private String title;
private String descriptionText;
private boolean completed;
private long dateDue;
private int priority;
private String userId;


public String getTaskId() {
    return taskId;
}

public void setTaskId(String taskId) {
    this.taskId = taskId;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescriptionText() {
    return descriptionText;
}

public void setDescriptionText(String descriptionText) {
    this.descriptionText = descriptionText;
}

public boolean isCompleted() {
    return completed;
}

public void setCompleted(boolean completed) {
    this.completed = completed;
}

public long getDateDue() {
    return dateDue;
}

public void setDateDue(long dateDue) {
    this.dateDue = dateDue;
}

public int getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

public void setPriority(int priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}

public boolean isAllDay() {
    return allDay;
}


public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
}
```

Now your json will look like this

```
    {
    "auth_token":"95dsfsdf758f75049",
   "taskId":"27878HG",
   "title":"my task",
   "descriptionText":"this is new task",
   "completed":false,
   "dateDue":1393911124000,
   "priority":1,
   "roleId":"GHsT-5sf1-4719-84E6F-8CGFR42189" 
}
```

and method your will be

```
   http://localhost:8080/myproject/api/task.json
```

and method is POST()
and add Request Headers Content-Type: application/json

Comment: Thank you for replying but I have edited my question. If you have any solutions regarding that please suggest me.

Comment: Hello @sameer Sir i am waiting for the reply.. I have edited my question. for your clear understanding

Comment: Hi sorry but I also don't know how to get values in your case.